Existence of universal coherence stuctures in higher-dmensional categories
Consider a weak $n$-category $\mathcal{C}$ for $n \geq 3$. We define a coherence structure on $\mathcal{C}$ to be a collection of higher cells that witness the coherence conditions between composites of $k$-morphisms for $1 \leq k < n$.
Let $\text{Coh}(\mathcal{C})$ denote the poset of coherence structures on $\mathcal{C}$, ordered by inclusion. We say that a coherence structure $S \in \text{Coh}(\mathcal{C})$ is universal if for any other coherence structure $T \in \text{Coh}(\mathcal{C})$, there exists a unique morphism of coherence structures $f: S \to T$ in $\text{Coh}(\mathcal{C})$.
Now, consider the 2-category $\mathbf{nCat}$ of (small) weak $n$-categories, weak $n$-functors, and weak natural $n$-transformations.
Does there exist a 2-functor $U: \mathbf{nCat} \to \mathbf{Cat}$ such that for any weak $n$-category $\mathcal{C}$, $U(\mathcal{C})$ is equivalent to $\text{Coh}(\mathcal{C})$, and moreover, $U(\mathcal{C})$ has an initial object corresponding to a universal coherence structure on $\mathcal{C}$?
If such a 2-functor exists, can we construct it explicitly? If it doesn't exist in general, under what additional conditions on $\mathcal{C}$ or $n$ does it exist?

Morphisms in a poset are always unique, so by "universal" you just mean a least element?

The question doesn't make a lot of sense. This object "Coh(C)" you are talking about isn't well defined. Especially  "Ordered by inclusion" doesn't mean anything: Coherence conditions aren't equations the composition operation need to satisfies, they are additional operation that need to exists. To some extend the first paragraph is roughly the idea of Maltsiniotis-Grothendieck definition of weak infinity categories, (if one remove the uniqueness of the morphism $S \to T$ that never holds) but they end up being very hard to relate to other more practical definition.
